# Facebook invite feature not working on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I tried to integrate facebook invite feature as follow! when I clicked on button `click here` it not shows me a dialog for me ( real is it shows about 0.1 second then it hiddens) ... Anybody can help me resolve this problem ! thank you!
this is my code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    FB.init({
    appId:'233108243711708',
    cookie:true,
    status:true,
    xfbml:true
    });

    function InviteF()
    {
    FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Welcome to 2my4edge',
    });
    }

    </script>

    <a href="#try" onclick="InviteF();"> 
    Click Here
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547404/invite-facebook-friends-on-a-website

Comment: thank you!! may be I should use send dialog to replace facebook invite feature

Comment: I've added it as an answer so that you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Send dialog to achieve what you want to do.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog